# Saving many to one without inline formsets - Django 2.1

Tags: django, one-to-many

What is the best procedure in Django for saving a form related to another model without the use of inline formsets?

**Problem setup:**

Model Address is related by a foreign key to Model User

Each User can have multiple Addresses. I want to add a new address to an User.

**views.py**

In the AddAddress class (extending CreateView) the form.errors has the error

> {'user': ['This field is required.']}

The user pk is in the url `/address/add/<int:pk>`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: @DanielRoseman This approach doesn't work because the view class form_valid method is called only if form.is_valid(). form has error as I specified

Comment: You didn't read it properly. It says to ensure the field is not in the fields list for the form.

Comment: I get django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: address.user_id . Adding the user_id field to the form.cleaned_data didn't work either

Comment: I saved the form without commiting, then I added the user to the resulting instance. It worked. I will write my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as Daniel Roseman noted, have to make sure the field "user" does not exist in the fields list of the form. This will make sure that the form is valid.

Override the form_valid method in the view class to save the form without commiting, then setting the required user to the resulting instance and then invoking the save directly on the it.

```
def form_valid(self, form):    
    address_obj = form.save(False)
    address_obj.user = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```